# Show block in /user/* page, not /user/*/edit

Tags: users, 8, blocks

From the Drupal 8 administration, I configured a block (block created from a custom module) for display it in /user/* pages.

[image]

It works; I see this block in /user/* and /user/*/edit pages.
Now, I want to display my block only from /user/* pages (the view mode), not from /user/*/edit pages (the edit mode).

Can I do that from the Drupal Administration page? I tested it adding "!/user/*/edit" but this has no effect.

[image]

If I can't, how can I do that from my custom module?

Comment: Try using /user/*/view instead.

Comment: Not work ;) with "/user/*/view", the block not showed from /user/4 or /user/4/edit by example

Comment: It could be that this condition plugin is too simple for your use case. Fortunately it is fairly easy to create a custom condition plugin in drupal 8.

Comment: I think too..what is a good way for manage this case from a custom module ? The block is already defined from my custom module in a Block Class

Comment: You can write your own condition plugin class. It has a method that returns true if the block should be visible.

Answer (score 10):

If you use this module then the exclamation prefix would work to exclude paths: https://www.drupal.org/project/block_exclude_pages

Answer (score 8):

For Drupal 8 install the [Route Condition Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/route_condition) and use the `entity.user.canonical` condition.

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 7 users you can use [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module and simple add page to path /user/* and ~/user/*/edit/ to exclude edit page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your own custom block plugin, you can have your build function return null on node edit pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called [Route Condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/route_condition) that allows you to specify exact routes (pages) to display blocks on. So for the user profile page the route would be `user.entity.canonical` (which is actually the example on the module page.

Answer (score -1):

### sometimes block display settings are all you need

Block displays are set per theme. You can sometimes simply disable the block on the theme used for `/*/edit` pages and leave it enabled on the theme used for `/user/` pages.

If your site is set up this way, you can avoid extra modules, custom code and complex workarounds.

### example

On a site using Claro as the admin theme (for other themes just substitute the name in the path):

- visit `/admin/appearance` to confirm there's a check in the box labeled "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" (if not, see note below)
- visit `/admin/structure/block/list/claro` and disable the unwanted blocks
- visit `/admin/structure/block` (the default theme block settings page) to confirm that the same blocks are still enabled

With this configuration they show at `/user/` but not at `/user/edit`.

### note

If your site doesn't already use the admin theme when editing or creating content, checking the box will change the display of all add/edit pages (e.g. `node/add/page` and `node/123/edit`). Have a look at all add/edit pages if you make this change, as it may cause some changes you'd need to address separately, like adjusting theme templates.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try just to hide on the pages you don't want it to be displayed instead of using "Show for the listed pages"? Change the option with "Hide for the listed pages" and add there user/*/edit and every other page where you don't want that block to be displayed.

Comment: _and every other page_: that would be a lot of pages!